# Write JavaDocs for external library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

My situation is I have an external compiled library (jar) from a 3rd party with no JavaDocs. As I'm developing I want to document the classes and methods by testing and using the very limited documentation I get from the website of the 3rd party.

My end goal is to have a JavaDoc documentation which I will be able to use in IntelliJ for the Code-Hinting and documentation lookup?

So my question is, is it possible to write JavaDocs to a already compiled jar file which I will be able to import? Perhaps using a tool which assists this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. All you have to do is write out the class and interface and method and variable definitions, *without any code*, as though all the methods were abstract, and then write Javadoc comments for those. This is actually how Sun produced the Javadoc, via a completely separate source tree controlled by the technical writers and editors (hi Doug!), with a merge process late in the build process for releasing the source code.

Comment: Could you show a quick code example? It would help make your answer clearer.

Comment: Just write out the methods as though they were abstract, without the `abstract` keyword, i.e. just a semicolon instead of the method body. You can't compile that, but you can Javadoc it.

Comment: This worked! I created a seperate project for this and did just as you said. The project will be full of errors but the JavaDoc generator has no issues with that. In my main project I attached the docs and it worked like a charm. Thank you :)